# How to replace whole node value in XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have 2 XML strings:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<album type="basic" shape="square" orientation="vertical">
    <page width="414" height="414" type="frontCover">
        <sbackground color="0xFFFFFF" locked="false" />
        <pbackground source="" rotation="none" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" locked="false" />
        <images/>
        <frame source="" rotation="none" locked="false" />
        <shapes/>
        <texts/>
    </page>

    <page width="414" height="414" type="backCover" useEntirePage="true">
        <sbackground color="0xFFFFFF" locked="false" />
        <pbackground source="" rotation="none" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" locked="false" />
        <images/>
        <frame source="" rotation="none" locked="false" />
        <texts/>
        <shapes/>
    </page>
</album>';

$replaceXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<album type="savedCard" sides="double" shape="square" orientation="vertical">
    <page width="414" height="414" type="frontCover" useEntirePage="true" >
        <sbackground color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <pbackground source="/images/1-2800-1860-1358622465873.jpg" rotation="none" x="-108.9" y="0" width="648.82" height="431" transparency="1" flipped="false" mask_frame_name="" />
        <images>
        </images>
        <frame source="" />
        <shapes>
        </shapes>
        <texts>
        </texts>
    </page>
    <page width="414" height="414" type="leftPage" useEntirePage="true" >
        <sbackground color="0xCBCBFF" />
        <pbackground source="" rotation="none" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" transparency="1" flipped="false" mask_frame_name="" />
        <images>
        </images>
        <frame source="" />
        <shapes>
        </shapes>
        <texts>
        </texts>
    </page>
</album>';
```

and need to do next: replace one of the node of first XML by value of same node from second one.

I need replace first page node in $xml by first page node of $replaceXml. So I need have this after replacement:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<album type="basic" shape="square" orientation="vertical">
    <page width="414" height="414" type="frontCover" useEntirePage="true" >
        <sbackground color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <pbackground source="/images/1-2800-1860-1358622465873.jpg" rotation="none" x="-108.9" y="0" width="648.82" height="431" transparency="1" flipped="false" mask_frame_name="" />
        <images>
        </images>
        <frame source="" />
        <shapes>
        </shapes>
        <texts>
        </texts>
    </page>

    <page width="414" height="414" type="backCover" useEntirePage="true">
        <sbackground color="0xFFFFFF" locked="false" />
        <pbackground source="" rotation="none" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" locked="false" />
        <images/>
        <frame source="" rotation="none" locked="false" />
        <texts/>
        <shapes/>
    </page>
</album>';
```

What is the best way to do this?

I tried next approach

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$replaceXml = simplexml_load_string($replaceXml);
$xml->page[0] = $replaceXml->page[0];
```

but it seems to be wrong, because I don't get what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this:

suppose we need replace first page

```
$pageNum = 0;

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);

$replace = new DOMDocument();
$replace->loadXML($replaceXml);

$newNode = $replace->getElementsByTagName('page')->item($pageNum);
$oldNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('page')->item($pageNum);

$newNode = $xmlDoc->importNode($newNode, true);
$oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $oldNode);

$xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

works as necessary